# upload video in app_data folder more then 4MB mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        //  Get all files from Request object  
        HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
            // Checking for Internet Explorer  
            if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
            {
                string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                fname +=testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                fname +=file.FileName;
            }

            response = new
            {
                status = true,
                message = fname
            };
            // Get the complete folder path and store the file inside it.  
            fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ClientVideos/"), fname);
            file.SaveAs(fname);
            
        }

      return  Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = new
        {
            status = false,
            message = "Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message
        };
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your web.config to change the maximum request size.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the `maxAllowedContentLength` in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

The value is in bytes.

Comment: I am using IIS 10, its not working

Comment: Its giving the error- 

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: answer updated, see the duplicate Q above

Comment: also the value changed from KB to bytes